# PHP - Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_next_result

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to retrieve multiple data sets from a MySql Stored Procedure with the following code and I get the error

"Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_next_result"

**I am using PHP Version 5.6.2** using MAMP (http://www.mamp.info/en/)

All the other code works until I try and add a second dataset to the results.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
    $mysql_host = "localhost";
    $mysql_database = "dbname";
    $mysql_user = "username";
    $mysql_password = "password";

    $link = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password ,$mysql_database);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $query = "CALL SprocName()";

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {

        mysqli_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $ID);

        $rtn = array();

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {  

            $resultrow = (object) [
                'ID' => $ID
            ];

            array_push($rtn, $resultrow);
        }


        mysqli_stmt_next_result($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $ID);

        $rtn2 = array();

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            $resultRow = (object) [
                'ID' => $ID
            ];

            array_push($rtn2, $resultRow);
        }

        echo json_encode(array('Result1' => $rtn, 'Result2' => $rtn2));

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    } else {
        echo "Failed";
    }

    mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: Does `mysqli_execute` support multiple queries, or you do need to use `mysqli_multi_query`?

Comment: please, try with this and let us know : php --version i still beleive that your are using an older version of PHP  : <5.3.0

Comment: php --version
PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2014 19:09:25) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies